# NodeJS > req.query is returning incorrect data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

I am sending a JSON (from Client-Side) to a NodeJS Server like this:

```
$.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "www.xyz.com/save",
  data: {

    designation: "Software Developer",

    skills: [

      "",
      "ASP.NET",
      "PHP",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "NodeJS",
      "",
      ""

    ]    

  } 

});
```

On the receiving end (i.e. the NodeJS Server), I print the JSON (with console.log) as follows:

```
save = module.exports = {};

save.setup = function( app ) {

  app.get( '/save', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.query);

  }); 

}
```

The problem is that **it prints the following**:

```
{

  designation: "Software Developer",

  skills: [

    "ASP.NET",
    "PHP",
    "NodeJS",

  ]    

}
```

i.e It is **missing the empty-string values** in the **skills array** (as I get it from req.query).

I have also checked the Network Panel (inside Developer Tools). It also shows the correct JSON.

Do anyone has any idea what may be going wrong ?

Comment: Try `req.body.skills`

Comment: This is a good question and it sounds like a qs issue like Josh said.  Nevertheless, I encourage you to rethink the approach rather than reconfigure the way you parse your query parameters--why does there need to be blanks in those arrays?

Comment: @tymeJV req.body.skills was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect (on which Express is built) uses the third-party [qs](https://npmjs.org/package/qs) module rather than the built-in [querystring](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module to parse URL query strings.

Your data gets serialized by jQuery into the following query string:

```
designation=Software+Developer&skills%5B%5D=&skills%5B%5D=ASP.NET&skills%5B%5D=PHP&skills%5B%5D=&skills%5B%5D=&skills%5B%5D=&skills%5B%5D=NodeJS&skills%5B%5D=&skills%5B%5D=
```

(That's multiple parameters named `skills[]` which include the blanks.)

If I give that string to [`querystring.parse()`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options)—the built-in parser—I get the result you're expecting:

```
{ designation: 'Software Developer',
  'skills[]':
   [ '',
     'ASP.NET',
     'PHP',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     'NodeJS',
     '',
     '' ] }
```

If I give the string to `qs.parse`, I get the same result you're seeing in your app.

[This behavior is an open `qs` issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring/issues/39), but it has been unresolved for over a year and a half.  You could bug TJ about it or try to fix the issue yourself.

In the meantime, you can work around the bug by using `querystring` rather than `qs`. I'd just use [`url.parse`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) to re-parse the original URL.

```
var url = require('url');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(url.parse(req.originalUrl, true).query);
});
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Just note that the "skills" array is now coming as "skills[]".

Comment: Hard to believe this is still an issue, but it is. And this saved me. Thanks!